# Programmatically save webpage AFTER all loading scripts have run

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to save a webpage. Using mechanize, I can save the HTML of the root page. However, there are many scripts that run after the page is loaded, filling several parts of the page with data that I would like to save to file.

I'm pretty sure I've seen that a library exists for this, but I can't remember the name, nor find it in my myriad searches. I think I saw that there is a library that acts just like a web browser, allowing it to load a page, run any JS scripts that need to be run, and then return the final page, as would be displayed in a real browser.

I'm not sure if it was python 2 or 3, but either would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library is [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g54xYVMojos is a video I made some time back to see selenium in action. Refer my answer to [How to load all entries in an infinite scroll at once to parse the HTML in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006940/how-to-load-all-entries-in-an-infinite-scroll-at-once-to-parse-the-html-in-pytho/) to see a sample usage of selenium

Comment: +1 I tried a few more searches, and found exactly that, though couldn't confirm it without testing yet. I'll give you the answer, and thanks for the confirmation. Grats!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)! It also has a [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) within python. Will update this answer and question for searchability for the community if it is indeed what I'm looking for.

Comment: FWIW see [praveen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21037397/1007939)'s answer. Exactly what I had found, and probably the answer I was remembering