# Href values are not being returned

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the url's for each restaurant from [this](http://www.delyver.com/Partners/partner/HSR%20Layout,%20Bengaluru,%20Karnataka,%20India/12.9081357/77.64760799999999) page and I have written a python script for the same:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.delyver.com/Partners/partner/HSR%20Layout,%20Bengaluru,%20Karnataka,%20India/12.9081357/77.64760799999999")

time.sleep(1)

elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

no_of_pagedowns = 40

while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1

post1 = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("Parwrsp.Parwrsp-Ado")


for post in post1:
    print post.get('href')
```

When i run the script, the browser window opens and i maximize its window size to obtain focus and it automatically scrolls down. But nothing gets printed. I implemented selenium following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006940/how-to-load-all-entries-in-an-infinite-scroll-at-once-to-parse-the-html-in-pytho) link.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current CSS selector would not match any element since `Parwrsp` is a class.

If you want to match multiple classes, write the selector this way:

```
.Parwrsp.Parwrsp-Ado
```

And, there is no `get()` method on a `WebElement` instance, you meant to use [`get_attribute()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute):

```
posts = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".Parwrsp.Parwrsp-Ado")
for post in posts:
    print post.get_attribute('href')
```

---

Proof of the above making sense:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> 
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get("http://www.delyver.com/Partners/partner/HSR%20Layout,%20Bengaluru,%20Karnataka,%20India/12.9081357/77.64760799999999")
>>> for post in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".Parwrsp.Parwrsp-Ado"):
...     print post.get_attribute('href')
... 
http://www.delyver.com/Partners/partnerdetailsview/947/Purnabramha,-HSR
http://www.delyver.com/Partners/partnerdetailsview/916/Moti-Mahal-Deluxe,-HSR-Layout
```