# Can't get beautiful soup to return the correct article titles, links, and img. Help debug?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape data for a project from the times for the last 7 hours. And yes it has to be done without the API. Its been a war of attrition, but this code that checks out keeps returning nans, am I missing something simple? Towards the bottom of the page is every story contained within the front page, little cards that have an image, 3 article titles, and their corresponding links. It either doesn't grab a thing, partially grabs it, or grabs something completely wrong. There should be about 35 cards with 3 links a piece for 105 articles. I've gotten it to recognize 27 cards with a lot of nans instead of strings and none of the individual articles.

```
import csv, requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

handle = 'http://www.'
location = 'ny'
ping = handle + locaiton + 'times.com'
pong = requests.get(ping, headers = {'User-agent': 'Gordon'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(pong.content, 'html.parser')

# upper cards attempt
for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'css-ki19g7 e1aa0s8g0'}):
print(i.a.get('href'))
print(i.a.text)
print('')

# lower cards attempt
count = 0
for i in soup.find_all('div', {"class":"css-1ee8y2t assetWrapper"}):
    try:
        print(i.a.get('href'))
        count+=1
    except:
        pass
print('current card pickup: ', count)
print('the goal card pickup:', 35)
```

Everything Clickable uses "css-1ee8y2t assetWrapper", but when I find_all I'm only getting 27 of them. I wanted to start from css-guaa7h and work my way down but it only returns nans. Other promising but fruitless divs are

```
div class="css-2imjyh" data-testid="block-Well" data-block-tracking-id="Well"
div class="css-a11566"
div class="css-guaa7h”
div class="css-zygc9n"
div data-testid="lazyimage-container" # for images
```

Current attempt:

```
h3 class="css-1d654v4">Politics
```

My hope is running out, why is just getting a first job is harder then working hard labor.

Comment: Show us the url. Then show us what you're trying to get. Also take a deep breath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked their website and it's using ajax to load the articles as soon as you scroll down. You'll probably have to use selenium. Here's an answer that might help you do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21008335/7933710