# Beautiful soup articles scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why does my code only finds 5 articles instead all of all 30 in the page?

Here is my code:

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}
    
    url = 'https://www.15min.lt/tema/svietimas-24297'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    
    antrastes = soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'vl-title'})
    
    print(antrastes)
```

Comment: You need to scroll the page to get all the contents. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006940/how-to-load-all-entries-in-an-infinite-scroll-at-once-to-parse-the-html-in-pytho) can help you using Selenium

Comment: this page use JavaScript to add elements but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't use `JavaScript`. It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`. And it may need also some JavaScript code to scroll page. Evntually you can check in DevTools in Firefox/Chrome if JavaScritp load data from some URL and you can try to use this URL with `requests`. It may need to use Session to get cookies and headers from first GET,

Answer (score 0):

Page uses `JavaScript` to add items but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`.

It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.
And it may also need some `JavaScript` code to scroll page.

Eventually you can check in `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` if `JavaScript` loads data from some `URL` and you can try to use this `URL` with `requests`. It may need to use `Session` to get `cookies` and `headers` from first `GET`.

---

This code uses URL which I found in `DevTools` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`).

It needs to set different `offset` (`date time`) in url to get different rows - `url.format(offset)`

If you use current datetime then you don't even need to read main page.

It needs header `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` to work.

It sends JSON data with keys `rows` (with `HTML`) and `offset` (with datetime for next rows).
And I use this `offset` to get next rows. I run this in loop to get more rows.

```py
import urllib.parse
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

url = 'https://www.15min.lt/tags/ajax/list/svietimas-24297?tag=24297&type=&offset={}&last_row=2&iq=L&force_wide=true&cachable=1&layout%5Bw%5D%5B%5D=half_wide&layout%5Bw%5D%5B%5D=third_wide&layout%5Bf%5D%5B%5D=half_wide&layout%5Bf%5D%5B%5D=third_wide&cosite=default'

offset = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for _ in range(5):
    print('=====', offset, '=====')
    
    offset = urllib.parse.quote_plus(offset)
    
    response = requests.get(url.format(offset), headers=headers)
    
    data = response.json()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data['rows'], 'html.parser')
    antrastes = soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'vl-title'})
    
    for item in antrastes:
        print(item.text.strip())
        print('---')
    
    offset = data['offset']  # offset for next data
```

Result:

```
===== 2022-03-09 21:20:36 =====
Konkursas „Praeities stiprybė – dabarčiai“. Susipažinkite su finalininkų darbais ir išrinkite nugalėtojus
---
ŠMSM į ukrainiečių vaikų ugdymą žada įtraukti ir atvykstančius mokytojus
---
Didėjant būrelių Vilniuje finansavimui, tikimasi įtraukti ir ukrainiečių vaikus
---
Mylėti priešus – ne glostyti palei plauką
---
Atvira pamoka su prof. Alfredu Bumblausku: „Ką reikėtų žinoti apie Ukrainos istoriją?“
---
===== 2022-03-04 13:20:21 =====
Vilniečiams vaikams – didesnis neformaliojo švietimo krepšelis
---
Premjerė: sudėtingiausiose situacijoje mokslo ir mokslininkų svarba tik didėja
---
Prasideda priėmimas į sostinės mokyklas: ką svarbu žinoti?
---
Dešimtokai lietuvių kalbos ir matematikos pasiekimus gegužę tikrinsis nuotoliniu būdu
---
Vilniuje prasideda priėmimas į mokyklas
---
===== 2022-03-01 07:09:05 =====
Nuotolinė istorijos pamoka apie Ukrainą sulaukė 30 tūkst. peržiūrų
---
J.Šiugždinienė: po Ukrainos pergalės bendradarbiavimas su šia herojiška valstybe tik didės
---
Vilniaus savivaldybė svarsto įkurdinti moksleivius buvusiame „Ignitis“ pastate
---
Socialdemokratai ragina stabdyti švietimo įstaigų tinklo pertvarką
---
Pokyčiai mokyklinėje literatūros programoje: mažiau privalomų autorių, brandos egzaminas – iš kelių dalių
---
===== 2022-02-26 11:04:29 =====
Mokytojo Gyčio „pagalbos“ – žygis, puodas ir uodas
---
Nuo kovo 2-osios pradinukams klasėse nebereikės dėvėti kaukių
---
Dr. Austėja Landsbergienė: Matematikos nerimas – kas tai ir ar įmanoma išvengti?
---
Ukrainos palaikymui – visuotinė istorijos pamoka Lietuvos mokykloms
---
Mokinius kviečia didžiausias chemijos dalyko konkursas Lietuvoje
---
===== 2022-02-23 10:11:14 =====
Mokyklų tinklo stiprinimas savivaldybėse: klausimai ir atsakymai
---
Vaiko ir paauglio kelias į sėkmę, arba Kaip gauti Nobelio premiją
---
Geriausias ugdymas – žygis, laužas, puodas ir uodas
---
Vilija Targamadzė: Bendrojo ugdymo mokyklų reformatoriai, ar ir toliau sėsite kakofoniją?
---
Švietimo ministrė: tai, kad turime sujungtas 5–8 klases, yra kažkas baisaus
---
```